# SQLDependency.Stop() - called but when QN Subscription times out, a message is dropped on the queue

Tags: c#, sql-server, notifications, sqldependency

**Scenario**

- Static Service Broker Queue and Service
- Use these static queues for SQLDependency subscription

**Rough outline of code**

Using [this blog post](http://blog.jsinh.in/monitoring-data-change-using-sqldependency-and-c/#.VpOi5fmLQdV) as a template the code roughly follows this pattern

- SqlDependency.Start(this.dbConnectionString, this.notificationQueueName);
- Configure Dependency targeting specific service (see code below)

  ```
      private async void ConfigureDependencyUsingStoreProcedureAndSpecificQueue()
      {
          if (null != this.sampleSqlDependency)
          {
              this.sampleSqlDependency.OnChange -= null;
          }

          if (null != this.sampleSqlCommand)
          {
              this.sampleSqlCommand.Dispose();
          }

          if (null != this.sampleSqlConnection)
          {
              this.sampleSqlConnection.Dispose();
          }

          this.sampleSqlDependency = null;
          this.sampleSqlCommand = null;
          this.sampleSqlConnection = null;

          //// Create connection.
          this.sampleSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(this.dbConnectionString);

          //// Create command.
          this.sampleSqlCommand = new SqlCommand { Connection = this.sampleSqlConnection };
          this.sampleSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          this.sampleSqlCommand.CommandText = this.notificationStoredProcedure;
          this.sampleSqlCommand.Notification = null;

          //// Create Sql Dependency.
          this.sampleSqlDependency = new SqlDependency(this.sampleSqlCommand, "service=" + this.notificationServiceName +"; Local database=" + this.databaseName, this.notificationTimeout);
          this.sampleSqlDependency.OnChange += this.SqlDependencyOnChange;
          await this.sampleSqlCommand.Connection.OpenAsync();
          await this.sampleSqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

          if (null != this.sampleSqlCommand)
          {
              this.sampleSqlCommand.Dispose();
          }

          if (null != this.sampleSqlConnection)
          {
              this.sampleSqlConnection.Dispose();
          }
  ```
- Handle SqlDependencyOnChange event as below. Calling the ConfigureDependency code again

  ```
  private void SqlDependencyOnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs eventArgs)
  {
      if (eventArgs.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Invalid)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("The above notification query is not valid.");
      }
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine("\nNotification Time: {0}", DateTime.Now);
          Console.WriteLine("\nNotification Info: " + eventArgs.Info);
          Console.WriteLine("Notification source: " + eventArgs.Source);
          Console.WriteLine("Notification type: " + eventArgs.Type + "\n");
      }

       switch (optionSelected)
          {
              case "1":
                  this.ConfigureDependencyUsingStoreProcedureAndDefaultQueue();
                  break;
              case "2":
                  this.ConfigureDependencyUsingStoreProcedureAndSpecificQueue();
                  break;
              case "3":
                  this.ConfigureDependencyUsingTextQueryAndDefaultQueue();
                  break;
              case "4":
                  this.ConfigureDependencyUsingTextQueryAndSpecificQueue();
                  break;
          }
  }
  ```
- Upon app shutdown call SqlDependency.Stop(this.dbConnectionString, this.notificationQueueName);. This returns true which according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224870(v=vs.110).aspx) means *the listener was completely stopped.*

**Issue Faced**

What I then see is that when the subscription reaches it's timeout period, it fires and drops a message onto the dependency queue waiting to be consumed.

If these messages stay in the queue, on next startup the app throws *The given key was not present in the dictionary.*

Also if I call SQLDependency.Stop() and leave the app running, it still consumes the QN fires for timeouts.

What step am I missing here as I am likely to face issues if messages are getting dropped on the static queue causing the *The given key was not present in the dictionary* exception.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> This returns true which according to the documentation means the listener was completely stopped.

This makes no promise with regard to the *server* state, nor the queue state. These will outlive your volatile application state, and at the next startup, you *will* find notifications from when your app was offline/shut down. You will have to code accordingly, with this expectation in place (eg. ignore keys that are not in the dictionary).

Note that even if `SqlDependency.Stop()` would attempt to stop the pending subscribed notifications, it is impossible to guarantee success as there could be notifications *in transit* (ie. pending delivery via Service Broker, notification may be in `sys.transmission_queue`). Waiting for all in transit notifications to drain delivery is also not feasible.

Additionally, your application would not handle backup-restore scenarios, as it is now. A restored backup *may* contain pending notification requests which will be invalidated upon restore and fire the notification message. When the application connects, it will find those unexpected notifications.

And ultimately, the application would not be able to handle its own disconnects/crashes. If you are relying on `SqlDependency.Stop()` to succeed before you can start successfully next time, you won't be able to start at all if you could not call `SqlDependency.Stop()` (=> any non-graceful stop).

For all these reasons, you *must* be able to handle keys not in the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Remus. I was hoping you would pick this up given your expertise in the area. By handling keys do you mean simply handling the exception and, what ignorning it? Also what will happen to the messages sitting on the queue, will these eventually disappear, or will they have to be cleared down manually?  So what does SQLDependency.Stop() actually do then if subscriptions stay there until they timeout anyway, at which point they fire and place a message on the queue reporting a timeout that, because the listener was stopped isn't consumed ? This could lead to hundreds of messages in the queue

Comment: [`SqlDependency.Stop`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDependency.cs) reference code is available for you to browse.

Comment: Notification messages sit in the queue until an application RECEIVEs them. With the default `SqlDependency` implementation, that creates a temporary service/queue, this issue is moot as a new queue gets created every time. If you use a long lived queue (which I approve of, btw) then you have to handle this situation. Perhaps RECEIVE any/all pending notifications *before* you call `SqlDependency.Start()` ?

Comment: Are you thinking something no more complicated than [RECEIVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186963.aspx) * from queue?  Also should I just handle and ignore the "keys not in dictionary" error?

Comment: I think RECEIVE is the easiest. Alternatives are [`DROP SERVICE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174990.aspx), [`ALTER DATABASE ... SET NEW_BROKER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) or iterating `sys.conversation_endpoints`. Each introduces more problems that it solves, imho. Of course, cleaning up the queue assumes only *one* application instance.

Comment: You need to loop `RECEIVE` because it will refuse to dequeue uncorrelated messages in one pass (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171615(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your help Remus. The only thing I am unsure of is how to handle the key was not present in the dictionary as this is thrown by SQLDependency.Start(). Given that I need to start the dependency I am not sure how I can handle this?

Comment: Perhaps you have to go to the lower level API of [`SqlNotificationRequest`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190270(v=sql.105).aspx). You would have to RECEIVE the notifications yourself and handle all the key query mapping. I haven't *done* such app myself.